# MySQL get different SUMs based on dates

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a Sql query where I can sums for 4 different date range.

```
SELECT t.TenantID, t.TenantFName, t.TenantLName, u.UnitName,
           TotalDebit, HousingDebit, TotalCredit, HousingCredit
    FROM Tenants t
    JOIN Units u ON t.UnitID = u.UnitID
    LEFT JOIN (
          Select
            TenantID,
            SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionTypeID = 1 AND ChargeTypeID != 6 THEN TransactionAmount ELSE 0 END) AS TotalDebit,
          From TenantTransactions
          Where TenantTransactionDate BETWEEN /* Here is my issue */
         Group By TenantID
         ) sums ON sums.TenantID = t.TenantID
   Where t.Prospect = 2
     AND t.PropertyID = 10
```

I am trying to return 4 sums:

1. For the last 30 days
2. For last 30-60 days
3. For last 60-90 days
4. Greater than 90 days ago

Does it make sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for totals based on the age of the transaction. We can get that by subtracting the transaction date from today to get a result in days:

```
datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate)
```

You want to group that into period by 30 days, so we use integer division to get a period:

```
datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate) DIV 30
```

And lastly, you want everything over 90 days grouped together:

```
if(datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate)<90,  datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate) DIV 30, 3)
```

This last expression returns a value  of 0, 1, 2 or 3. We can use that to group the transactions, and total them:

```
SELECT TenantID, 
       sum(TransactionAmount) as totalDebit, 
       if(datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate)<90,  datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate) DIV 30, 3) as period
FROM TenantTransactions 
where TransactionTypeID=1 and chargeTypeID != 6
group by tenantID, period
order by tenantID, period
```

Now you should be able to plug that back into your original query, and sort them:

```
SELECT t.TenantID, t.TenantFName, t.TenantLName, u.UnitName,
           TotalDebit, HousingDebit, TotalCredit, HousingCredit
    FROM Tenants t
    JOIN Units u ON t.UnitID = u.UnitID
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT TenantID, 
         sum(TransactionAmount) as totalDebit, 
         if(datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate)<90,  datediff(now(), TenantTransactionDate) DIV 30, 3) as period
       FROM TenantTransactions 
       where TransactionTypeID=1 and chargeTypeID != 6
       group by tenantID, period
   ) sums ON sums.TenantID = t.TenantID
   Where t.Prospect = 2
     AND t.PropertyID = 10
   order by t.tenantID, sums.period
```